# Spark - move data from tables to new table with extra column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, tuples, rdd

So we have a Cassandra project and it requires us to migrate a large number of tables from 3 separate tables into one.

e.g. `table_d_abc`, `table_m_abc`, `table_w_abc` to `table_t_abc`

Essentially data needs to be moved to this new table with an extra column with a value that was in the table's name.
There are 100's of tables like this - so you could imagine the huge job it would be to 'hand-make' a migration script. And naturally I thought SPARK should be able to do the job.

---

e.g.:

```
var tables = List("table_*_abc", "table_*_def") // etc
var periods = List('d','w','m')

for (table <- tables) {
  for (period <- periods) {
    var rTable = table.replace('*', period)
    var nTable = table.replace('*', 't')
    try {
      var t = sc.cassandraTable("data", rTable)
      var fr = t.first
      var columns = fr.toMap.keys.toArray :+ "period"
      var data = t.map(_.iterator.toArray :+ period)

      // This line does not work as data is a RDD of Array[Any] and not RDD of tuple[...]
      // How to ???
      data.saveToCassandra("data", nTable, SomeColumns(columns.map(ColumnName(_)):_*))
    } //catch {}
  }
}
```

versus:

```
var periods = List('d','w','m')

for (period <- periods) {
  sc.cassandraTable("data","table_" + period + "_abc")
    .map(v => (v.getString("a"), v.getInt("b"), v.getInt("c"), period))
    .saveToCassandra("data", "table_t_abc", SomeColumns("a","b","c","period"))

  // ... 100s of other scripts like this
}
```

---

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Is there a way to programatically save an extra column from an source with unknown number of columns and datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the RDD objects must be of a type which has a "RowWriter" defined. This maps the data in the object to C* insertable buffers.

#### RDD World

Using "CassandraRow" objects this is possible. These objects allow for generic contents and can be constructed on the file. They are also the default output so making a new one from an old one should be relatively cheap.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/CassandraRow.scala

You would make a single RowMetadata (basically schema info) for each table with the additional column, then populate the row with the values of the input row + the new period variable.

#### Dataframe World

If you wanted to switch to Dataframes this would be easier as you could just use the DataFrame add column before saving.

```
cassandraDF.withColumn("period",lit("Value based on first row"))
```